# three numbers are chosen at random between 0 and 1. what is the probability that the difference between the greatest and the least is less than 1/3?

Tags: probability

three numbers are chosen at random between 0 and 1. what is the probability that the difference between the greatest and the least is less than 1/3?
I have seen a solution with calculus, but is there a non-calculus way to do it?

Comment: Any approach I know of relies on at least Measure Theory and the Lebesgue integral. Some Lebesgue integrals can be converted into Riemann integrals, which would fall under the heading of Calculus. So, are you asking for a method using Lebesgue integrals that could not be converted to Riemann integrals? It is not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: Just for fun: If the question were instead asking for $P(\max - \min < \frac12)$, then the answer is $\frac12$ by a symmetry argument.  Alas, you asked for $P(\max - \min < \frac13)$ and the symmetry argument in my head doesn't generalize to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that all three chosen numbers are at least $\frac{2}{3}$.  Let $B$ be the event that the first number chosen is the smallest of the three, is less than $\frac{2}{3}$, and is within $\frac{1}{3}$ of the others.  The probability we want is, by symmetry, $P(A)+3P(B)$ (the extra factor of $3$ from choosing which number is smallest).

We have $P(A)=(\frac{1}{3})^3$.

For $B$ to occur, we first need our first number $x$ to be less than $\frac{2}{3}$ (which occurs with probability $\frac{2}{3}$).  Conditioning on this, the probability the next two numbers are both in $[x,x+\frac{1}{3}]$ is $\frac{1}{9}$.

Putting it all together, the probability is
$$\frac{1}{27}+(3)(\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{9})=\frac{7}{27}$$

Comment: +1 very nice!!  When I tried to visualize the three numbers as a random point in the unit cube, I had a really hard time visualizing the feasible region.  But this method breaks down the region into a cube plus three prisms with square bases (where the prisms are "sheared" i.e. the sides are not perperdicular to the base) and gives the volume of each.  Excellent!